# Changing the call log screen and pushing own call-id's blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

Is there a way to change the order of the call log screen in blackberry?  Lets say I want to add two call-id entries to top of the latest call log. Is that possible?  If it is which part of the API should I look at?

Any sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [PhoneCallLog](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/phonelogs/PhoneCallLog.html) object?  Browsing the [API docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/index.html) is a good place to start with any BlackBerry question.